# Unable to run vagrant up or homestead up Virtualbox with the name homestead exists?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

> A VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead' already exists. Please
>   use another name or delete the machine with the existing name, and try
>   again.

I've tried removing the machine from virtual box (deleting the files as well)

I've tried running vagrant destroy and homestead destroy as well.

I cant see to run homestead up or vagrant up. I keep getting the error i've stated above.

My VirtualBox\ VMs are empty.

> ➜  homestead  homestead up Bringing machine 'default' up with
>   'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date... A VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead' already exists. Please
>   use another name or delete the machine with the existing name, and try
>   again. ➜  homestead

Running vagrant global-status brings this:

5cd65e5  default virtualbox poweroff /Users/username/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead

Im not sure how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: go to Users\username\VirtualBox VMs and delete `homestead` folder. then try running `vagrant up` once more

Comment: Which virtual machines are listed when you run `vagrant box list`?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually delete the `homestead` in VirtualBox Gui. Open your VirtualBox Gui select homestead, click machines select poweroff.You can now delete homestead by selecting remove, and delete all related files, or go to `Users\username\VirtualBox VMs` and delete `homestead` folder as suggested by @Digitlimit.In your `homestead` directory, run

```
vagrant up
```

again